# Как записать значение 65535 в short Java

Tags: java

В книге "Java SE 8 Базовый Курс" К. Хорстманна наткнулся на задачку:

"***Напишите программу, вводящую 2 числа в пределах 0-65535, сохраняющую их в переменных типа short и вычисляющую их сумму, разность, произведение, частное и остаток без знака, не преобразуя эти величины в тип int.***"

Пробовал задействовать `Short.toUnsignedInt()`, но по условию задания, нужно записывать в переменные типа short. Как это сделать?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Просто считайте за точку отсчета -32768 и при выводе компенсируйте

Comment: Просто не читайте больше книжки Хорстманна. Судя по задачке, не тому он учит..

Answer (score 1):

`short` – 16-битное целое число, диапазон значений которого – `[-(2^16)/2;(2^16)/2-1]` или `[-32768; 32767]`. Длина этого диапазона – `2^16` или `65536`.

Вам необходимо с помощью `short` оперировать числами из отрезка `[0;65535]`. Для этого, при вводе числа, можно вычитать из него некоторое смещение, которое будет равно `32768`.

Вот пример:

```
public class Main {
    private static final int sOffset = 32768;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        short firstValue = stringToShort("2");
        short secondValue = stringToShort("65535");

        System.out.println("firstValue[short]: " + firstValue);
        System.out.println("secondValue[short]: " + secondValue);

        System.out.println("firstValue[original]: " + shortToInt(firstValue));
        System.out.println("secondValue[original]: " + shortToInt(secondValue));

        System.out.println("multiplication: " + shortToInt(firstValue)*shortToInt(secondValue));

    }

    private static short stringToShort(String value) {
        return (short) (Integer.parseInt(value) - sOffset);
    }

    private static int shortToInt(short value) {
        return value + sOffset;
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
firstValue[short]: -32766
secondValue[short]: 32767
firstValue[original]: 2
secondValue[original]: 65535
multiplication: 131070
```

Возможность хранения результата операций в `short` я ставлю под сомнение, так как в общем случае результат может быть вообще числом не целым.

Comment: Это всё довольно очевидно, а умножать-то без int как?

Comment: @andreymal, А надо ли?

Comment: Не знаю, но в вопросе это таки упоминается)

Comment: Попробовал вывести в консоль произведение 50000 и 60000 (с использованием сдвига -32768) получилась какая-то лажа, а не 3 000 000 000.
(a + offset) * (b + offset) вроде неявное приведение к int есть, нет?

Comment: @andreymal, В общем случае, результат может быть вообще числом не целым, поэтому я полагаю, что ограничение только на входные данные.

Comment: @Богдан, Перед умножением необходимо прибавлять к числам смещение. А Вы уверены, что результат тоже должен быть `short`?

Comment: @post_zeew, я переписал условие задачи дословно, и что имел в виду автор не совсем понимаю. Создаётся впечатление, что это просто задача с подвохом, который ускользает от понимания...

Answer (score 1):

Умножение, деление и остаток будут считаться через **int**. А потому можно предположить, что автор хотел обратить внимание на особенности приведения типов.
Соответственно, допустим следующий ответ:

```
public class Exercise_1_07 {

    /*
    Напишите программу, вводящую два числа в пределах от 0 до 65535, 
    сохраняющую их в переменных типа short и вычисляющую их сумму, разность, 
    произведение, частное и остаток без знака, не преобразуя эти величины в тип int.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите первое число: "); short var1 = (short) in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Введите второе число: "); short var2 = (short) in.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Первое число как short:       %6d , и как int: %10d\n", 
                var1, (0x0000FFFF & var1));
        System.out.printf("Второе число как short:       %6d , и как int: %10d\n", 
                var2, (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        short sum = (short) ((0x0000FFFF & var1)  + (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        System.out.printf("Сумма чисел как short:        %6d , и как int: %10d\n",  
                sum, (0x0000FFFF & var1) + (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        short diff = (short) ((0x0000FFFF & var1) - (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        System.out.printf("Разность чисел как short:     %6d , и как int: %10d\n", 
                diff, (0x0000FFFF & var1) - (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        short mult = (short) ((0x0000FFFF & var1) * (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        System.out.printf("Произведение чисел как short: %6d , и как int: %10d\n", 
                mult, (0x0000FFFF & var1) * (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        short div = (short) ((0x0000FFFF & var1) / (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        System.out.printf("Частное чисел как short:      %6d , и как int: %10d\n",  
                div, (0x0000FFFF & var1) / (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        short rem = (short) ((0x0000FFFF & var1) % (0x0000FFFF & var2));
        System.out.printf("Остаток от деления как short: %6d , и как int: %10d\n",  
                rem, (0x0000FFFF & var1) % (0x0000FFFF & var2));

    }
}
```

И результат:

```
Введите первое число: 42015
Введите второе число: 952
Первое число как short:       -23521 , и как int:      42015
Второе число как short:          952 , и как int:        952
Сумма чисел как short:        -22569 , и как int:      42967
Разность чисел как short:     -24473 , и как int:      41063
Произведение чисел как short:  21320 , и как int:   39998280
Частное чисел как short:          44 , и как int:         44
Остаток от деления как short:    127 , и как int:        127
```

Answer (score 0):

Упражнение дано к первой главе книги, в которой вводятся базовые понятия языка Java и, кроме всего прочего, описываются примитивные типы и диапазоны их допустимых значений.

Смысл данного задания в том, чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать результат приведения вводимых данных, или вычислений, к типу, который имеет "более узкий" диапазон допустимых значений чем необходимо, и вызвать у начинающего программиста именно такую реакцию как у вас )

Делать это задание надо в лоб, то есть без учета "смещения в отрицательный диапазон".

В следующей редакции этой книги (Core Java SE 9 for the impatient, 2nd ed.), данная задачка оперирует уже типом int:

```
Write a program that reads in two integers between 0 and 4294967295, stores
them in int variables, and computes and displays their unsigned sum, difference,
product, quotient, and remainder. Do not convert them to long values.
```

Answer (score 0):

С применением оператора `Short.toUnsignedInt()`:

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random g = new Random();
        short s1 = (short) g.nextInt(65536);
        short s2 = (short) g.nextInt(65536);
        System.out.println("Первое число = " + Short.toUnsignedInt(s1));
        System.out.println("Второе число = " + Short.toUnsignedInt(s2));
        System.out.println("Сумма = " + (Short.toUnsignedInt(s1) + Short.toUnsignedInt(s2)));
        System.out.println("Разность = " + (Short.toUnsignedInt(s1) - Short.toUnsignedInt(s2)));
        System.out.println("Произведение = " + (Short.toUnsignedInt(s1) * Short.toUnsignedInt(s2)));
        System.out.println("Частное = " + (Short.toUnsignedInt(s1) / Short.toUnsignedInt(s2)));
        System.out.println("Остаток = " + (Short.toUnsignedInt(s1) % Short.toUnsignedInt(s2)));
    }
}
```